# git rebase workflow with branches

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have taken a branch X out of master. I work on it. I push some part of it to the server, from time to time. Then to take master changes i rebased my branch X on the master. Did i go wrong at this step because i had made my branch public ?

after this i merged my changes in my local master and pushed up to server both master and X.

i had to do --force for branch X.
what should be the workflow i should follow ?
should we be working on same branch X simultaneously ? Should i never use rebase in on that case ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's resume what happened :
After pushing your branch X with some work on it to master, your git graph looked like that from what I understand :

```
                   master (same as origin/master)
                    v
A------B------C-----F
              \
               D-----E
                     ^
                     X (same as origin/X)
```

You rebased X on top of master :

```
                   master (same as origin/master)
                    v
A------B------C-----F
              \     \
               \     D'----E'
                \          ^
                 \         X
                  \
                   D-----E
                         ^
                      origin/X
```

And that's where you hit your issue : you cannot push `X` anymore because `origin/X` and `X` diverged. (and accepting the push of your local branch would mean rewriting `origin/X` history, which could cause big trouble for whoever you are working with :) )

What I usually do in that case is to consider `origin/X` a trashable branch. If I rebase `X` locally, I use a different remote branch for it. Another thing you could do is simply cherry-pick or merge the things you want from master.